# AJAX History state for Rails remote form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, browser-history

I'm attempting to make the browser history (back/forward buttons) work for my Ruby on Rails site.  I followed the following rails cast episode:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/246-ajax-history-state

I was able to get all AJAX links converted but I'm having problems with remote forms.

Here's what I attempted:

edit.html.erb:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@post,
                    url: post_path(@post.id),
                    remote: true) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input(:comments) %>
  <div class="browser-history-mgmt" 
    <%= f.button(:submit,
                 value: "Save") %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

application.js:

```
$(function () {
  $('.browser-history-mgmt input').unbind('click').bind('click', function () {
    var action = this.form.getAttribute("action");
    history.pushState(null, '', action);
    //TODO: call getScript and return false instead of true
    return true;
  });

  $(window).bind("popstate", function () {
    $.getScript(location.href);
  });
})
```

This nearly works but if I attempt to Save without the required comments, the address bar gets updated to the "show" address while I remain on the "edit" form. (I believe implementing the TODO would fix that ... but I'm at a loss for exactly how to implement that.)

I'm not even sure if I'm going down the right path here.  The railscast episode is nearly 5 years old now.  Is there an easy way to get browser history working on remote forms in Rails?

Comment: Ever figure this out? Seems overly hard to find an up-to-date tutorial on this.